# d3 timeout like angular $.timeout

Tags: d3.js

The situation is I need to load data for a long time, and I need to show a loading icon when loading, but it seems d3 stop my jquery code. My loading icon only display when the calculateAroundCenter function finished, I think it is because the jquery execute after the d3 scope end.

```
$("#loadingBox").show()
calculateAroundCenter();
```

so how to show the icon?  Like  $.timeout in angularjs, I wish you know this js.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

D3 doesn't provide anything for this, but you can easily make your own as follows:

```
showLoadingIcon();
d3.json(url, function(error, data) {
  // do something with the data
  removeLoadingIcon();
});
```

I've used this technique [here](http://larsko.org/v/mpte/).